# Intellij right click context menu problems in Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-10.10

I have a problem exactly described in http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/292434;jsessionid=771E7DC3F119EA0C822164B3A4556372?tstart=0 however I am just using the plain Intellij with Ubuntu.

OS: Linux-Ubuntu-10.10 (32 bit)- Latest

Desktop Manager : GNOME default

JDK: JDK 1.6.0_24 Oracle Latest update

IDEA: 10.0 Latest build

Build: IU-103.72

click and hold right mouse button -> context menu shows up -> release mouse button -> context menu disappears I am normally used to that the context menu stays open in that case without holding the mouse button.

The workaround mentioned in the article works but it is too much of a pain for someone who codes 6-7 hours a day.

Can someone please provide some options along where/what I should debug etc. All other applications work perfectly fine (including Eclipse !)

1) I have already tried disabling Compiz (System -> .. ->Visual effects)
2) I have also put the mouse sensitivity to the minimum

UPDATE: Ok I was using the Eclipse theme for keyboard shortcuts (ie, trying to use the same keyboard shortcuts of eclipse in Intellij) when I flipped back to default ones it works !!!

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/225242/ . SuperUser is more appropriate place for such questions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indeed, it's a problem specific to the Eclipse keymap in IDEA, I've submitted http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66182 to track it, please watch/vote.

I've also found a workaround for this problem which is very simple:

> Open Settings | Keymap, press Copy button to create an editable copy of the Eclipse keymap, in the copy find "Show Context Menu" action in the Other group, it has multiple shortcuts defined, delete "Button3 Click" from the list of shortcuts, press Apply. Context menu will no longer disappear after right click.

Answer (score 0):

I am on ubuntu 10.04 64bit with a new IntelliJ Community Edition (10.0.2) and I do not have such problems. Have you tried opening IntelliJ option menu and change the Appearance? Or try changing the Ubuntu's theme?

Such right-click behaviour is not in the spirit of Ubuntu and it's rather weird.

PS. Try booting Live CD (like 10.04) and install IntelliJ IDEA and see if you experience the same behaviour with the default settings.

Comment: I've checked the same issue on IU edition (build IU-99.18) and I HAVE NO problems with the right click!

Comment: Almost all forums that I have read this on, mentioned 32 bit for their machines. I can try the xfce window manager though

Comment: I haven't checked on 32bit system. Have you tried the LiveCD? It's the fastest way to check 32/64bit systems with the default config.

Comment: I updated the Q, when I change Shortcut settings to use Eclipse this issue happens. I flipped it back to default and looks fine !