# Anybody experiences problems in contextual menus behavior?

Tags: rubymine

Dear RubyMine Overflowers,

I downloaded the latest version of RubyMine (3.2.1) on a Mac running SL 10.6.8 and latest apple provided Java.

I am experiencing some problematic behavior regarding the mouse right-click.

I can bring up contextual menus only by **double** right-clicking. if I single right-click, the menu comes up very instantly and disappears.
After some experimentation, I have concluded that if I right-click and manage to keep the mouse pointer at the exact pixel as before r-clicking, contextual menu disappears. If the pixel before right-click is different than the one after r-click the Contextual menu stays. (Imagine the chaos when this applies to the Project window: i get constant warnings of moving files).

Anybody experiencing such funny stuff in RubyMine? or otherwise, any way to change mouse pointer sensitivity?

Many thanks...

Petros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is similar issue, but it's known to affect only Linux users with Eclipse keymap:
[Intellij right click context menu problems in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178850/intellij-right-click-context-menu-problems-in-ubuntu).

I can't reproduce it on Mac, but the question above is worth checking, maybe the suggested workaround will work for you.