# Why menus and context menus of IntelliJ are instantly closing after beeing opened?

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, intellij-idea, fedora

when I open a context menu or menu of the menubar it opens only for some milliseconds and then gets closed instantly. Did you ever experienced such behavior? Any suggenstions to fix this?

I'm using *Fedora 15 64-bit* with Java-JDK *1.6.0_26* and I got an ultimate version of *IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellij right click context menu problems in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178850/intellij-right-click-context-menu-problems-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you are using Eclipse keymap, and [there is an easy fix for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178850/intellij-right-click-context-menu-problems-in-ubuntu/5181624#5181624).

See also the [related bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-16709) in IDEA tracker.